# Scale a Join LINQ statement to multiple table

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have come up with some LINQ code to join multiple tables together with multiple fields "dynamically", meaning that the user chooses it's table and field he want's to join on. But I have a hard time scalling this to multiple tables with out doing like I've dome here:

```
if (Tables.Count == 2)
{
    result = from dataRows1 in Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in Tables[1].AsEnumerable() 
             on new ComparableObject(new List<DataRow> { dataRows1 },KeyFieldToJoinOn[0].Item1) 
             equals new ComparableObject(dataRows2, KeyFieldToJoinOn[0].Item2)
             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(
                 dataRows1.ItemArray.Concat(dataRows2.ItemArray)
                 .ToArray(), false);
}
else if (Tables.Count == 3)
{
    result = from dataRows1 in Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in Tables[1].AsEnumerable() 
             on new ComparableObject(new List<DataRow> { dataRows1 }, KeyFieldToJoinOn[0].Item1) 
             equals new ComparableObject(dataRows2, KeyFieldToJoinOn[0].Item2)
             join dataRows3 in Tables[2].AsEnumerable() 
             on new ComparableObject( new List<DataRow> { dataRows1, dataRows2 },KeyFieldToJoinOn[1].Item1) 
             equals new ComparableObject(dataRows3, KeyFieldToJoinOn[1].Item2)
             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(
                 dataRows1.ItemArray.Concat(dataRows2.ItemArray)
                 .Concat(dataRows3.ItemArray)
                 .ToArray(),false);
}
```

I've saw the dynamic-LINQ library but I haven't seen much comprehensive documentation on how to join dynamiclly. All of this comes from the fac that I can't do a sql query on a data table wich would make things easier because I could buil my query.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use the foreach loop to iterate through the table rather than writing these if else conditions. You could also use LINQ to filter the table contents as per your requirement.